# Send file to server and open window at the same time

Tags: javascript, php

I want to send a csv file to the server, and open a separate window to process the file.

I know I can send the file to the server using

```
function send_xml_data_to_server(txt,url) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = some_function;
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    xmlhttp.send(txt);
}
```

Though this is not going to open a new window with the specified url. To open a new window, I need to use

```
window.open(url);
```

I could use `window.open` inside the specified url (to open the same url), but this doesn't look optimal.

How can I send a text file to some php file, and open that php file in a new window at the same time? Is this possible?

Comment: the xhr request is mostly asynchronous. sou you need to wait until its uploaded. you could show a loading icon and then open the new window. thats actually the way it´s done properly

Comment: So I put the window.open() inside my "some_function". But how do I pass the contents of the file together with the window.open()? I can't use a GET parameter, because of size limitation (at least).

Comment: I did it using the approach from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp, but I'm getting a new Tab in Firefox, when I wanted a new window (like in window.open)...